# Should Node.js only be used for "apps"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Should Node.js be the basis of a website or be used only when certain functionality (eg. a chat room) is needed?

For example, in certain project, I'm using npm and have a `node_modules` folder and a `package.json` file in the main directory where all my code is.

However, the question I'm asking is whether or not this is good practice? Should Node.js only be used in, for example a `chat-room/` folder? Or is it OK to use the same Node.js installation across an entire website, using when needed?

Comment: Node.js can be used for anything*. Using node as the base of your website or app is very common. A website is an "app"

Comment: A server that handles ports and renders HTML markup *is* an application. Sure, it might not yet *dynamically* react to requests, but it already is doing quite a lot.

Comment: Node doesn't have any routing functionality. Anyway, I can't understand what you mean by "app", or "main structure", or "within your website". As it stands, it's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many companies recently are having a hard job to detach their front end code from their server, hence, if you are starting a project from scratch, this is something you want to avoid.

Having low coupling applications will give you the flexibility to change your whole Front End stack without changing a single code in your API. Moreover, you will be able to use your API from different applications. They will now work independently.

The routing is how you define the URL, verb and opt parameters.

I hope that is what you have been struggling with.